# TypeORM QueryBuilder add parameter that is in string

Tags: typeorm, query-builder

I want to add query parameter to my queryBuilder but it returns error `invalid input syntax for type json`. What is the correct way to send this parameter?

My query:

```js
const foundedUserContacts = await this.userBookContactRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('userBookContacts')
  .select(['userBookContacts.contacts'])
  .andWhere(`contacts @> '[{ "phoneNumber": :phoneNumber }]'`, {
    phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
  })
  .getMany();
```

This works ok:

```js
const foundedUserContacts = await this.userBookContactRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('userBookContacts')
  .select(['userBookContacts.contacts'])
  .andWhere(`contacts @> '[{ "phoneNumber": "${user.phoneNumber}" }]'`)
  .getMany();
```

My schema is:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'userBookContacts' })
@Unique('userUuid_userPhone', ['userUuid', 'phoneNumber'])
export class UserBookContact {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  userUuid: string;

  @Index()
  @Column()
  phoneNumber: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'jsonb',
    nullable: true,
    default: '[]',
  })
  contacts: UserContact[];

}
```

Comment: Please provide us `userBookContacts` schema and additional information about input: what is `user`, what type of it's params? Error may happen because of missing `"` after params escaping. May be fixed using `contacts @> '[{ "phoneNumber": ":phoneNumber" }]'`

Comment: I added entity, `:phoneNumber` in quotes but it also doesn't work:
`error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0`